# Android - Event after createView

Tags: android, layout

I want to get `width` and `height` of my layout **after** it had been drawn.

My code is actually called in the `createView()` method. But I want to wait until the layout is drawn before execute this code :

```
Log.i(TAG, "Height: "+myButton.getHeight()+" - width : "+myButton.getWidth());
// result is Height: 0 - width : 0
```

Is there any event launched after `onCreateView()` call ?

Comment: You can try onActivityCreated() after onCreateView().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a global layout listener has always worked well for me.  It has the advantage of being able to remeasure things if the layout is changed, e.g. if something is set to View.GONE or child views are added/removed.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     // inflate your main layout here (use RelativeLayout or whatever your root ViewGroup type is
     LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout ) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null); 

     // set a global layout listener which will be called when the layout pass is completed and the view is drawn
     mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               //Remove the listener before proceeding
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
               } else {
                    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
               }

               // measure your views here
          }
     }
 );

 setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Depending on your usage, you might want to remove the listener when you're done with it as shown.

Comment: Thanks it works fine ! A question : what is the cleanest method ? Your or "try onActivityCreated() after onCreateView()." ?

Answer (score 0):

`createView` does not exits. I suppose you mean `Fragment.onCreateView`
inside `onCreateView`,

```
onCreateView(...) {
  View view = infalter.inflate...
  final View button = view.findViewById
   view.post(new Runnable() {                
       @Override
       public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Height: "+button.getHeight()+" - width : "+button.getWidth());

        }
    });
  return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  [onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) is what you are looking for.
Keep in mind that it is called whenever the window focus changes.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            Log.i(TAG, "Height: "+myButton.getHeight()+" - width : "+myButton.getWidth());
}
```